# UI Router - how to store data between states without passing them explicitly to $state.go(...)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have language code in `Gallery`component:

```
function Gallery(LanguageService) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
     $ctrl.code = LanguageService.language;
     _loadGallery($ctrl.code);
  }
}
```

`LanguageService` is service which contains global language settings. For example, codes can be `en` for english and `pl` forpolish.  From `Gallery` I can move to `Image details` component, where `$onInit` looks the same - take code from language and load data. Problem is that I can add Image translation, for example german translation - `de`, and it will change `LanguageService`. And then:

1. On `Image` I have german language version
2. I can click `Go back` button to go back to Gallery
3. But `Gallery` does not have german translation and I will get `404 Not Found`

At first glance, I can pass to `Image` state `galleryLanguage`:

```
$state.go("image.details", {id: image.id, galleryLanguage: $ctrl.language});
```

But it is lost without explicit definition in every `image` states, for example if from `image.details` I want to go to `image.edit` I have to do:

```
$state.go("image.edit", {id: image.id, galleryLanguage: $ctrl.language});
// And if I want to bo back to gallery
function goBackToGallery() {
  $state.go(`gallery.details`, {galleryLanguage: $ctrl.galleryLanguage}); //and then in Gallery use it if present
}
```

Of course it can be done with additional service:

```
function Gallery(LanguageService, TemporaryService) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
      $ctrl.code = TemporaryService.language? TemporaryService.language : LanguageService.language;
      TemporaryService.language = undefined;
      _loadGallery($ctrl.code);
  }

  function goToImageDetails(image) {
    TemporaryService.language = String($ctrl.code);
    $state.go('image.details', {id: image.id});
  }
}
```

But maybe it can be done with Angular UI router, without own implementation? Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: Create parent abstract state that will store current language.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov It sounds interesting, but will I be able to update it? I can change language from `gallery.details` state (switching between different translation for gallery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can use params option in your route

```
.state('about', {
        url: '/about?isDraft',
        params: {
         isDraft: null
        }
      })
```

2- You can use services as you stated

3- You can store your data in sessionStorage

These are my options.

Comment: For me it looks like I have to add `?isDraft` to all routes in `image`s components ("childs" cause they are nested like `gallery/2/image/4`) to retrieve it in `gallery.details` state. I'm afraid I have to use service, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you would better to use service

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using ui-route without parameter. see example below:

**Method one:**

```
.state('eventListing', {
    url: '/events',
    templateUrl: 'views/eventListing.html',
    controller: 'eventListing',
    resolve: {
        category: function() {
            return { id: 1 };
        }
    }
})
```

In controller u acces it like:

```
app.controller('eventListing', ['$scope', 'category',
    function ($scope, category) {
        $scope.categoryId = parseInt(category.id);
    }
]);
```

**reference** [resolve in ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

**Method two:**

Here you don't need resolve, just pass object with data key in ui-router state and access in controller using **$state.current.data**. see below example:

```
  .state('eventListing', {
    url: '/events',
    templateUrl: 'views/eventListing.html',
    controller: 'eventListing',
    data: {
        id: 1
    }
  })
```

In controller u acces it like:

```
app.controller('eventListing', ['$scope', '$state',
    function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.categoryId = parseInt($state.current.data.id);
    }
]);
```